# Fast Search Server 2010 Crawl

Tags: fast-for-sharepoint

I am new to FAST.  I have a quick question on FAST/SharePoint Search.  For example, i have 1000 items in SharePoint List called ListA.  First time, when i do full crawl, my 1000 items will get crawled and indexed.  When i do search for particualr item i can see in the search results page.  I Added more 500 Items from ListA.  Then i did incremental crawl, i searched for an item which is Added from 500 items.  Now i can see the item. Thats correct.

Here is my question.:
  Without doing the incremental crawl, is it possible to get the results back ? I dont want to schedule the incremental crawl on hourly basis or m

Answer (score 2):

The only way for content to be returned by a query is for it to be indexed. The only way for content to be indexed is for it to have been crawled.

Hourly incremental crawls are common. If you're concerned about performance you can crawl a WFE that isn't used by end users. If you have so much data that the crawl does introduce a performance issue, you should look at improving your infrastructure or redesigning your information architecture.

Comment: I have one more question on WFE.  When the user request a URL, it directly hits one of the WFE's, but what happens at the same time if wfe's is schduled for crawling... ? Does it impact on user experiences ?

Comment: Technically, though you are not likely to experience a difference. Think of the crawler like a user who is just quickly viewing every page you have in your farm. This user waits for the page (and all linked inline content like images) to load completely and then "clicks" a link on the page, repeating the process. This "user" isn't even uploading documents or editing items so they're not really causing a heavy load. The real load is on your crawl server as it is building the index as it crawls the content. If your crawler is your WFE then maybe that could be an issue in the future.